# Are python and/or vala questions on-topic on this site?

Tags: discussion

I have seen few questions on [python](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) and [vala](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vala).

I would like to know are python and/or vala, on-topic on this site?

Moreover, *if python/vala is off-topic*, we are not supposed to close every question relates to python/vala. Here, what I mean is,

When is it appropriate to ask questions about python/vala ?

Also is [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4032/python-header-missing-cannot-compile-cryptography) question, off-topic?

*I know generic programming questions are on-topic on SO and OP might get better service on Stack Overflow which is really all about programming*

Answer (score 1):

Programming questions should only be on topic when about elementary, or some elementary specific software, such as the pantheon-file-chooser.